# api.user_timeline not grabbing full tweet

Tags: tweepy

I'm not being able to get full tweets with more than 140 characters with timeline method in Tweepy. I'm aware that the of the API default mode is compact rather then extended. But I but couldn't solve this issue with my code. Any tips? Thanks a lot!

```
tweets = []
username = 'BorisJohnson'
count = 200

try: 
    for tweet in api.user_timeline(id=username, count=count, include_rts=False):
        tweets.append(tweet.text)
except BaseException as e:
      print('failed on_status,',str(e))
      time.sleep(3)
print(tweets)
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Tweepy documentation](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/extended_tweets.html), try replacing `tweets.append(tweet.text)` with `tweets.append(tweet.full_text)`

EDIT: Here's the full working code:

```
tweets = []
username = 'BorisJohnson'
count = 200
try: 
    for tweet in api.user_timeline(id=username, count=count, include_rts=False, tweet_mode="extended"):
        tweets.append(tweet.full_text)
        print(tweets)
except BaseException as e:
    print('failed on_status,',str(e))
    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: I tried but it returns the following message: failed on_status, 'Status' object has no attribute 'full_text'
Out[21]:

Comment: Try with `for tweet in api.user_timeline(id=username, count=count, include_rts=False, tweet_mode="extended")` and then `tweets.append(tweet.full_text)`

Comment: I get this: File "<ipython-input-37-b71fbb60113a>", line 6
    for tweet in api.user_timeline(id=username, count=count, include_rts=False, tweet_mode='extended')
                                                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I just ran the code and compared it to non-full variant and it worked. I'll edit my answer and wll paste full code. Just to be sure, i'm using Tweepy 3.8.0 with Python 3.8

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new here. Where can I get the full code? Thanks a lot again!

Comment: It's in original answer, I edited it so code can be seen clearly